# How to shorten the url link in facebook share....?

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8

I developing WP 8 application.

In my app Facebook share functionality is present.

Sharing work correctly. but i need to shorten the URL value present in share.

[image: my output]

First share show the full url value.

but in second share it's only show the CHENNAI.BURRP.COM

I try with following code.

Try1- [I know it's not correct]

```
string urlvalue = "http://chennai.burrp.com/listing/tuscana-pizzeria_nungambakkam_chennai_outdoor-caterers-restaurants/1494314960";
```

Try -2

Use hyper link in xaml code

```
 <Hyperlink x:Name="Link" NavigateUri="http://chennai.burrp.com/listing/tuscana-pizzeria_nungambakkam_chennai_outdoor-caterers-restaurants/1494314960" > TAVG </Hyperlink>
```

C#

```
 string urlvalue = Link.NavigateUri.ToString();
```

Both code not working for me.

plz tell how to show url value present in second share[image].

My share code

```
         string result = Command.Text;
         string heading = Nametb.Text;
         string heading2 = Apptb.Text;
         string review = Ratingtb.Text;
         **string urlvalue = "http://chennai.burrp.com/listing/tuscana-pizzeria_nungambakkam_chennai_outdoor-caterers-restaurants/1494314960";**

         FacebookClient.Instance.PostMessageOnWall(result + Environment.NewLine + heading + Environment.NewLine + heading2 + Environment.NewLine + review + Environment.NewLine + google, new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(PostMessageOnWallCompleted));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're able to bind, you could do something like this, and bind the shortened URL to the Run's `Text`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.website.com"
        RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        <Run Text="{Binding ShortenedLinkDescription}" />                         
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

**EDIT**

Here, I found [this](http://mvpway.wordpress.com/2013/03/28/how-to-navigate-to-an-url-from-your-windows-phone-8-application/).  Just sent the Content property of hyperlink, or bind a value to it, and your hyperlink will show up as whats in Content, rather than the full URI.

Comment: The member "RequestNavigate" is not recognized or is not accessible.